# How to synchronize iPhone local database to online database when online database has changed?

Tags: iphone, sql, core-data, soap, synchronization

Currently my app pulls data from an Microsoft SQL 2005 database via ASP.NET XML web services using SOAP whenever it needs data.

I would like to change my app so that it has a local database, and this database would check to see if the data has changed and synch itself to any new data.

How do i tell if there is any new data?

Do i just count the number of rows in the SQL table and if it less than the number of rows in the CoreData database then re-write the CoreData database?

Is there a way to tell only sync the records that have changed or been added/deleted?

Should i be synching all data when the app starts or synching only the table that corresponds to the loading view?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are clever with your schema design than you can. The best option is probably to add 'created_at' and 'updated_at' date fields to your database tables (and set them whenever you modify or create records). Then in your sync request query, select all records that have a date greater than the highest date in your local database. This will work for a ONE way synchronization. TWO way synchronization is much more difficult and requires thought on contact resolution.

As for syncing, I'd recommend doing it in the background whenever possible. You should be able to use the `NSFetchedResultsController` to handle updating your views when new records are fetched. This way the user won't experience any annoying loading screens.

Comment: Things are usually a bit more complicated because of deleted records. Also, date/time as a type is notoriously bad for tracking changes due to clock drift, time zone differences and daylight savings. Ever-increasing sequence numbers are usually much better.

Comment: btw, I agree that from a 10k ft view, this is what needs to be done. The details though are far from trivial, even w/o conflict resolution.

Comment: Good point Remus. It definitely won't handle deletes (that would probably require some sort of soft delete). However, I'm currently using the time stamp method to manage syncs in an app and it seems to be working. I generate all timestamps form within the database (then query using the latest from the core-data attribute, not the device time). Will this still suffer from the issues you mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: If you use local times yes, specially because of the daylight saving issues. Using UTC times is better.

Comment: I Like the idea of using created_at and updated_at fields, i would always use the server time to stay consistent. So lets say that the person loads the app and synchronizes the database for the first time. When the user comes back and loads the app, i decide i want to synchronize. Do i now, check every record to see if it currently exists, if it does not add it to the local database. If it does exist check the updated_at field and if the date is greater than the current date in the local database, update that record?

Comment: You would write a query to have your database return only records that are out of sync. Something like `SELECT * FROM data WHERE created_at > {created_at} OR updated_at > {updated_at}`. You can get the `created_at` and `updated_at` from the existing core data store. Once the fetch returns, iterate over the data on the iOS device. Check to see if a record already exists (by querying on the `id` field. exists. If it does, update it. Otherwise, create it.

Comment: Hmmm, i might be confused. But would this mean that the database does a query per record? as in if i have 100 records i have to hit the database 100 times to synch?

Comment: No, you don't do multiple calls for a single sync. You are only executing a single SELECT query (the query I pasted). It will return zero or more records. These records are the *only* records that need to be updated on the device.

Comment: Will this not cause the records on the device to have various created_at and updated_at times? Please explain where i am storing the created_at and updated_at variables on the device. I am still confused. Sorry!

Comment: Yes... You are storing a `created_at` and `updated_at` date for each record. That way, you can tell when they change...

Comment: If each record on the device has their own created_at and updated_at time, then am i not running a query to check each local records created_at and updated_at times versus the remote database's created_at and updated_at times... that would me 100 queries for 100 records.... i think i must be missing how to do this.

Comment: The only way i could see doing this is to store 1 instance of updated_at variable and then doing the SELECT * FROM data WHERE updated_at > {updated_at(variable given from the device}.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to detect what has changed in the database since you last connected. SQL Server offers two frameworks for this: [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) and the [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx). For a comparison of the two, see [Comparing Change Data Capture and Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519.aspx). These frameworks are leveraged by the .Net [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992) to automate data synchronization.

Unfortunately, none of these are available in SQL Server 2005. They are all SQL Server 2008 features, so you would have to upgrade.

With SQL Server 2005 you can only track the changes manually. There are several approaches, all imperfect, and they all revolve around either triggers and tracking tables, or around tracking row versions with a TIMESTAMP (the problem is always how to track *deleted* rows).

While Core-Data has buil-in support for synchronization (see [Syncing Core Data Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/SyncServices/Articles/UsingCoreData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005232-SW1)), it is not usable with your scenario.